# spilt the sum of singular values of matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

Let $A_{i} \in GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ for $i=1, 2, 3.$ For $q>0$, we denote $t_{3}^{q}=\sum_{i=0}^{3} \sigma_{1}^{q}(A_{i})\sigma_{2}^{q}(A_{i})\sigma_{3}^{q}(A_{i})$, $t_{2}^{q}=\sum_{i=0}^{3} \sigma_{1}^{q}(A_{i})\sigma_{2}^{q}(A_{i})$ and $t_{1}^{q}=\sum_{i=0}^{3} \sigma_{1}^{q}(A_{i})$, where $\sigma_i$ are singular values ($\sigma_i \geq \sigma_{i+1}$).

It is easy to see $$t_{2}^{q_1} t_{1}^{q_2} \geq B,$$

where $B:=\sum_{i=0}^{3} \sigma_{1}^{q_1 +q_2}(A_{i})\sigma_{2}^{q_1}(A_i).$

Can we find a lower bound for $B$ that is similar to $t_{2}^{q_1} t_{1}^{q_2}$? I meant the lower bound splitted to $t_{2}$ and $t_{1}$(for instance, some uniform constant times $t_{2}^{q_1} t_{1}^{q_2}$).

Comment: Is $t_3^q$ meant to be part of the question? I see it defined, but not actually used or asked about anywhere.

Comment: @NathanielJohnston : No, it is not. I just wanted to show the general fornula